# Assigning arguments to aggregate with variable substitution and paste()

Tags: r, conditional-statements, aggregate, paste

I am writing a web interface to do stats on a large dataset. Widgets will allow the user to select variables and groups. Each variable is associated with a kind of statistic that can be performed. The web page calls an R script that sets up the appropriate data frame to pass to “aggregate” and then to various outputs. The data here is not relevant so I’ve not included it.

My problem is with flexible input to “aggregate” that is bombing out for reasons I can’t figure out:

```
group variable “grp”
str(grp)
'data.frame':   1573 obs. of  1 variable:
 $ Loc: Factor w/ 4 levels "ED","ICU","Trans",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 4 ...

Time variable
TimeBase <- “year”

data
str(tmp)
'data.frame':   554 obs. of  4 variables:
$ Loc     : Factor w/ 4 levels "ED","ICU","Trans",..: 4 1 1 1 4 4 1 1 4 4 ...
$ year    : Factor w/ 7 levels "2011","2012",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
$ ActivLag: num  3 -2 0 1 17 210 19 -7 0 107 ...
$ ScanLag : num  80 12 5 8 159 255 28 109 11 111 ...

aggregate(formula(paste0(". ~", names(grp), " + ", TimeBase)), data = tmp, paste0(stvar), na.rm = TRUE, na.action = na.pass)
```

this works fine if stvar = “ mean”, but if stvar = “sum”, which doesn’t take na.rm as an argument, it does not work. So, I tried the following:

```
statstrg <- ifelse(stvar %in% c("sum", "prop","frel", "median"), " na.action    = na.pass", " na.rm = TRUE, na.action = na.pass")
aggregate(formula(paste0(". ~", names(grp), " + ", TimeBase)), data = tmp,  paste0(stvar), paste0(statstrg))
```

which does not work and gives the follwoing error:

```
Error in if (na.rm) x <- x[!is.na(x)] else if (any(is.na(x)))  return(x[FALSE][NA]) : 
argument is not interpretable as logical
```

Even though

```
aggregate(formula(paste0(". ~", names(grp), " + ", TimeBase)), data = tmp, paste0(stvar), na.action = na.pass)
```

DOES work for stvar = “sum”.

Using a conditional string assignment and paste(var) for each of na.rm and na.action = na.pass doesn’t work since there is no way to handle the commas needed for aggregate to parse arguments. I’ve tried passing various combinations of arguments in a paste(), but aggregate wants to see individual arguments. So can anyone point me to a method that might work better? thx.

Comment: the function `sum()` also takes this `na.rm=T/F` argument bdw

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While formulas can be generated dynamically with strings, parameter assignments in functions cannot be built from string such as optional arguments, `na.rm` and `na.action` in `aggregate()` whose default values are `NULL`.

Consider conditionally assigning two different `aggregate()` calls depending on *stvar*:

```
if (stvar %in% c("sum", "prop", "frel", "median")) {
    aggdf <- aggregate(formula(paste0(". ~", names(grp), " + ", TimeBase)), data = tmp, 
                       FUN = stvar, na.action = na.pass)
} else {
    aggdf <- aggregate(formula(paste0(". ~", names(grp), " + ", TimeBase)), data = tmp, 
                       FUN = stvar, na.rm = TRUE, na.action = na.pass)
}
```

Alternatively, assign a variable *st_narm* conditionally to `TRUE` or `NULL` which requires using `if` instead of `ifelse` since you cannot assign an empty object to a value (replacement length failure).

```
if(stvar %in% c("sum", "prop","frel", "median")){
  st_narm <- NULL
} else {
  st_narm <- TRUE
}

aggdf <- aggregate(formula(paste0(". ~", names(grp), " + ", TimeBase)), data = tmp, 
                   FUN = stvar, na.rm = st_narm, na.action = na.pass)
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for good suggestions! The issue is solved, but to take each for completness:

1) "aggregate" will not take sum() as an argument, only "sum" and the na.rm is passed from "aggregate" and not through sum() and will give an error if sum and na.rm are both passed at the same time.

2) The  if-then st_narm <- NULL method still gave me an error: Error in if (na.rm) x <- x[!is.na(x)] else if (any(is.na(x))) return(x[FALSE][NA]) : 
  argument is of length zero. So did not work.

3) The conditional with the full "aggregate" strings worked well, though seems less elegant somehow. But, gets the job done.

Thx again. Gotta love the opensource community!

Comment: Great. And I tested both solutions on sample data and both worked. It must be data specific in the error you get. Which aggregate fct. causes that error: *sum*, *median*, *quantile*, etc.? Maybe try *FALSE* instead of *NULL*. Also, those are not strings but `aggregate()` method calls.